# Error when attempting to Set a Tile in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get this error:

> In order to call GetTransformInfoExpectUpToDate, RendererUpdateManager.UpdateAll must be called first.
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

when trying to do this:

```
public void Test()
{
    Tile floorTile = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Tile>();
    Tilemap tilemap = GameObject.Find("Tilemap").GetComponent<Tilemap>();

    floorTile.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Scenes/Maze/Sprites/Terrain/white256") as Sprite;
    tilemap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(0, 0, 0), floorTile);
}
```

The tilemap is getting found (!= null); I can see the sprite in the viewport

*using unity 2023.2.2f1*

**Edit:**
So I changed the "Detect Chunk Culling Bounds" option in the tilemap to "Manual" and now no errors are getting displayed. I still have no idea why it does this though.